# HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile can't find file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Web App with script and publish it to a web site. I am at the very first experimental level where I want the `doGet` function to execute

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyPage')
```

and I get the `"Not Found"` error.

MyPage is a simple HTML file that outputs "Hello World".  If I change the script to

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Hello World')
```

the code executes just fine when the URL is linked. It appears that the HTML file I created for the `doGet` function to access and output can't be found although I have saved it and saved a version of the project that includes it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

It does not need the extension. But it does need to be an HTML file created with File > new Html File.

Answer (score 0):

The Google developer page explains this fairly well and gives an example to start:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

In a nutshell:
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('x'): instructs GAS to print "x" to the page.

HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('0'): instructs GAS to read and print the code inside of 0.html to the page (*note the use of '0' instead of '0.html' as GAS knows you are pointing to a HTML file.)
To create the html file inside of GAS, click the top left "file" button and go "new" -> "html".

Answer (score -1):

`HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyPage')` needs the `.html` extension. So `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyPage.html')`

Or is it more complicated than that?